# Install ruby-debug-ide on Snow Leopard running Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: installation, ruby, gem

I am trying to install ruby-debug-ide on Snow Leopard running Ruby 1.9 so that I can debug ruby code in Netbeans.

I am using the following command

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide19
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
nathan:mark-moseley-ruby-debug-ide-9eb626b nathan$ sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide19
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide19:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/ruby
 --with-ruby-dir
 --without-ruby-dir
 --with-ruby-include
 --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
 --with-ruby-lib
 --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib
/Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:268:in `block (2 levels) in read': Looking for http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p160.tar.gz and all I got was a 404! (URI::NotFoundError)
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1194:in `block in transport_request'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2342:in `reading_body'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1193:in `transport_request'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1170:in `block in request'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:239:in `block in read'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:286:in `connect'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:234:in `read'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/contrib/uri_ext.rb:128:in `download'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:55:in `block in create_makefile_with_core'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tempfile.rb:320:in `open'
 from /Users/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.4/lib/ruby_core_source.rb:51:in `create_makefile_with_core'
 from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'
Requesting http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.2-p160.tar.gz


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/linecache19-0.5.11/ext/trace_nums/gem_make.out
```

Anyone know how I can get it installed?

Note I have the latest xcode installed but I installed Ruby 1.9 using RVM, which I also used to set it as the default ruby environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by installing Ruby using homebrew (brew install ruby). Seems the version RVM installs has some issues (I experienced the same thing with various gems).

I had to manually modify the symlinks after installing Ruby with homebrew as by default your system will still use Ruby 1.8 which comes with xcode.